# selecting only one row for each product in the table in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, select

I have a bit complex mysql select query question.

I have 2 tables as shown in the image below. One is for products and the other one is the images of products. I can select the products with images with inner join.

But, since there are a lot of items in the "product images table", I want to select just one image from the table for each product.

Here are my 2 main tables :
[image]

and here is the desired result table :
[image]

It doesn't matter which image is retrieved from the images table but to make it less complex I can -for example- get the min(imageID) one.

I want to use this query to display products in my e-commerce page.
I don't want to get all the images on page is loaded. So, just one image for each product is ok for me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want exactly one column from the image table (e.g. productImage) or more than one column? Do you want to join product and image table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually implement this as a join with exists logic:

```sql
SELECT pImageID, productID, productImage
FROM productImages p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM productImages p2
    WHERE p2.productID = p1.productID AND
          p2.pImageID < p1.pImageID
);
```

In plain English, this says to select every product image record having the smallest `pImageID` for each group of `productID` records.

Comment: Thanx Tim, as far as I understand, this query also protects me from the records for the products in which have no image. Correct?

Comment: Yes, correct, because it directly queries the product images table.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use ROW_NUMBER() analytic function like here:

```sql
--  S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table products (PRODUCT_ID Int, PRODUCT_NAME Varchar(32));
Insert Into products (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME) VALUES
(1, 'Sample product 1'), (2, 'Sample product 2'), (3, 'Sample product 3'),
(4, 'Sample product 4'), (5, 'Sample product 5'), (6, 'Sample product 6'),
(7, 'Sample product 7'), (8, 'Sample product 8'), (9, 'Sample product 9');

Create Table productimages (IMAGE_ID Int, PRODUCT_ID Int, PRODUCT_IMAGE Varchar(32));
Insert Into productimages (IMAGE_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_IMAGE) VALUES
(1, 1, 'images/img1.jpg'), (2, 1, 'images/img2.jpg'), (3, 1, 'images/img3.jpg'),
(4, 1, 'images/img4.jpg'), (5, 2, 'images/img5.jpg'), (6, 2, 'images/img6.jpg'),
(7, 2, 'images/img7.jpg'), (8, 3, 'images/img8.jpg'), (9, 3, 'images/img9.jpg');
```

```sql
--      S Q L :
Select   i.IMAGE_ID, i.PRODUCT_ID, i.PRODUCT_IMAGE
From  ( Select      i.IMAGE_ID, i.PRODUCT_ID, i.PRODUCT_IMAGE, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By i.PRODUCT_ID Order By i.PRODUCT_ID) "RN"
        From        productimages i
      ) i
Where  RN = 1;
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t : 
IMAGE_ID    PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_IMAGE
----------  ----------  -----------------
         1           1  images/img1.jpg
         5           2  images/img5.jpg
         8           3  images/img8.jpg    */
```

Didn't use products table since your expected result (for sample data provided) could be fetched from productimages table. If you would need to fetch something from products table (product name or something else) then you should join products table....

Answer (score 1):

One option is to get the earliest imageID for each product, then join this dataset with images and products tables to ensure only products with images are included :

```
SELECT i.*
FROM products p
INNER JOIN productImages i ON p.productID = i.productID
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT productID, MIN(pImageID) AS MIN_pImageID
  FROM productImages i
  GROUP BY productID
) AS t ON t.productID = i.productID AND t.MIN_pImageID = i.pImageID
```